# add self-defined objects into planning scene Rviz MoveIt!

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just like adding a box or a cylinder into the planning scene in Rviz, could anyone shed light on how to add self-defined objects to the planning scene so as to do collision detection and motion planning?

What I would like to add is a curved surface (a bezier surface). I can easily draw these curved surfaces using OpenGL, so is there a way to import them to the planning scene in Rviz?

I am thinking probably getting CAD models and importing CAD models is another way to solve the problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212610/add-self-defined-objects-into-planning-scene-rviz-moveit!/) by [Huitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22131/huitan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Importing mesh models to the planning scene is what I need :) Meshes in .stl, .dae and OGRE meshes are supported. Thanks for your attention!

---

Originally posted by [Huitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22131/huitan/) with karma: 63 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0